# How to render MVC 3 View after $.ajax post params to its Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have asked here [How to send js variables to mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848710/how-to-send-js-variables-to-mvc-controller) how to send js vars to MVC 3 controller action, and I get it. But now I have another problem - i cant render a view with my recieved params.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/css/jquery.Jcrop.css")" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.Jcrop.js")"></script> 
    <title></title>


<script>
    function submitForm() {

        var coords = new Object();
        coords.x1 = 120;
        coords.y1 = 240;
        coords.x2 = 360;
        coords.y2 = 480;


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateCover")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ coordinates: coords }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
    <body>   
    <input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
</body>



public ActionResult CreateCover(ImageCoordinates coordinates)
{
    ViewData.Model = coordinates;
    return View();
}
```

I successfully recieved my params in action in debug, but action does not render my view, I am still at that page that i sent params from. What should i use to render my next page?

Comment: Dont use ajax as it wont return a fully rendered page. You are using json as the return type in the call. Change the dataType to 'html' and use a partialview to set the content of a div. eg. success: function (data) { $('#targetdiv').html(data)}..

Comment: Have a look at : http://rhamesconsulting.com/2012/09/14/using-jquery-ajax-method-to-pass-json-to-a-mvc3-action-and-return-a-partial-view/ for an example.

Comment: I dont want to return values to the same page. I want to receive vars in my controller from my view, process them, and than render other view

Comment: In this case you need to do another ajax on the first ajax success, post the "data" you received and get html response, render it as Steve posted.

Comment: @CadmusX , I understand what you are trying to do. If you have a look at the link I posted, it will explain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the solution -

Say your model is -

```
public class ImageCoordinates
{
    public int x1 { get; set; }
    public int x2 { get; set; }
    public int y1 { get; set; }
    public int y2 { get; set; }
}
```

and then your JQuery POST -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function submitForm() {

        var model = new Object();
        model.x1 = 120;
        model.y1 = 240;
        model.x2 = 360;
        model.y2 = 480;


        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "@Url.Action("CreateCover")",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify({ coordinates: model }),
            success: function (data) {
                window.location.href = data;
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="submitForm()" />
```

Then your controller action would be -

```
public ActionResult CreateCover(ImageCoordinates coordinates)
{
    return new JsonResult() { Data = "http://www.google.com", JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

So basically, you construct the URL to which you want the page to be redirected. Then send that URL as JsonResult. On the client side, in the Success function you catch the returned URL and make a redirect using window.location.href.