# Send js variables to mvc controller

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

[How to send js variables to mvc controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848710/how-to-send-js-variables-to-mvc-controller)

I am trying to work out the code provided as answer to the above question by - ramiramilu.

However It seems I am still getting 0 as output in my controller.

The model and view look the same as the answer suggests.
However, as I am using dot net core with MVC my code in controller side looks like -

Controller code -

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class PieController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult GetChartDetails(PieConcs piecord)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Javascript code -

function sendJson(){

```
    var model = new Object();
    model.x1 = 120;
    model.y1 = 240;
    model.x2 = 360;
        model.y2 = 480;
        alert('here');


    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetChartDetails")",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify({ piecord: model }),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        failure: function (errMsg) {
            alert(errMsg);
        }
    });
}
```

Model class -

```
public class PieConcs
{
    public int x1 { get; set; }
    public int x2 { get; set; }
    public int y1 { get; set; }
    public int y2 { get; set; }
}
```

The code for view is written in the Index.cshtml file.
I am new to MVC, so please let me know if anything more in detail is required to better the question.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?  It's not clear what you're asking.  Where are you "getting 0 as output"?

Comment: Can you share your JS?

Comment: As it stands you're not outputting any number from your controllers. You're outputting a View and a null value.

Comment: @David - I am fetching the values in controller - same as the answer (for the question that I am following)

Comment: @AbhishekD: What "values"?  Are you asking why your `GetChartDetails` method isn't returning a value?  It's returning `null`.  What are you expecting this code to do and why?  Please clarify details about the problem you're facing.  Stack Overflow is not a scavenger hunt, while your question can certainly *reference* other questions, it should not be dependent upon other questions for clarity and content.

Comment: @David - I am just trying to get the values in the piecord variable. Which I am checking with a break-point. Sorry I should have explained that earlier.

Comment: @AbhishekD: What is the structure of the `PieConcs` class?  In your browser's debugging tools, in the network tab, what exact data is being posted to the server?  Maybe you don't want to use `JSON.stringify` but just send the object as-is?

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript do something like:

```
let dataToSend = {
        objectProp1: ...,
        objectProp2: ...,
        ...
    }

    fetch('Pie/GetCharDetails', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(dataToSend)
    }).then(response => response.json());
```

Keep in mind that object props must have exaclty the same name as your PieConcs props.